# Proving continuity and differentiability of a function at a point

Tags: functions, continuity

Let f be a real valued function satisfying

|f (x) − f (a)| ≤ C |x − a|ⁿ for some n> 0 and C > 0

(a) If n = 1, show that f is continuous at a

(b) If n > 1, show that f is differentiable at a.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck. Add that to your question to avoid downvotes and closing.

Comment: a) f(x) is continous at $a$ if $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) = f(a).$  Write down the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition of the limit and see if something related to the given condition doesn't appear.  b) What is the definition of $f'(a)$  can you organize it such that something close to the given condition is there?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $n=1+\varepsilon$.
Then, $$\frac{|f(x)-f(a)|}{|x-a|}\leq C|x-a|^\varepsilon.$$

Great ! $a$ is even a stationary point !